# Haar measure, can image of modular function be any subgroup of $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: topological-groups, haar-measure

It is easy to find examples of locally compact second countable Hausdorff topological groups $G$ whose modular function $\Delta$ has image $\{1\}$ or $(0,\infty)$. Are there groups $G$ of this kind for which the image of $\Delta$ is *anything* else?

Comment: The $ax+b$ group of a $p$-adic field?

Comment: $S\ltimes \mathbb{R}$ for any subgroup $S<\mathbb{R}^*_+$?

Comment: For any *countable* group (since $G$ will have the topology of $|S|$ disjoint copies of ${\bf R}^*_+$).

Comment: For any $S$ whatsoever, taking it with the discrete topology (and $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual one). In case $S$ is not countable, the group will not be second countable, though. This rases the question: which subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ (or $\mathbb{R}$ to that matter) are homomorphic images of locally compact second countable groups. I suppose these are the countable ones, or $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ itself, and nothing else. But I haven't thought about it enough.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, I don't see how the $ax+b$ group works. And Uri I thought the semidirect product of unimodular groups was unimodular (its Haar measure is absolutely continuous with respect to the product measure).

Comment: The $ax+b$ group over ${\bf R}$ is the standard example of a non-unimodular group, and is a semidirect product of the additive and multiplicative groups.  @UriBader's suggestion is the subgroup of such transformations with $a \in S$.

Comment: @nullUser, no, in general semidirect product of unimodular groups are not unimodular (but, yes, their Haar measure is absolutly coninuous wrt the product measure). In fact, I wonder what was the example you had in mind when you wrote that it is easy o comep up with an onto modular function if it wasn't a sd product.

Comment: @UriBader, I believe my original "example" was more of a "grave oversight". Could you recommend a reference that goes through the connection between semidirect products and their modular functions?

Comment: @nullUser I like Folland, "Abstract harmonic analysis" which I suppose treat some examples, but I believe the best thing for you (if you haven't done it beofre) would be to work through the example of "ax+b" over the reals.

Comment: @UriBader, I've worked through the "ax+b" example but in the context of 2x2 matrices. That's why I'm looking for somewhere that goes over it as a semidirect product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure what is the question.
The answer to the question appearingin in the body is given in a comment by Noam Elkies and the answer to the question given in the title is given by a comment of mine.
Let me answer a third question which is implied and it is less trivial:
which subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ appear as images of the modular homomorphism of second contable locally compact groups (lcsc).

I claim the list is $\{1\}$, $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ and all of its countable subgroups.

The class of subgroups under consideration coincides with the class of subgroups of $\mathbb{R}^*_+$ obtained as all images of continuous homomrphism of lcsc groups, as could be seen by a semi direct product construction. In fact, I may consider only injective homorphisms, by moding out the kernel. In particular, I may assume my groups are abelian and with no compact subgroups. The connected component of such group is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence must be mapped onto for $n>0$ (and in this case $n=1$), so I may assume my group is totally disconnected. A totally disconnected group with no nontrivial compact subgroup must be discrete, so my group is actually countable.